# Adjusting the position of a component in Angular

Tags: angular, components

I have the first component that calls the second component. The second component renders **under** the first component. What I want to achieve is the second component will render **beside** the first component. I have no clue if I should be editing the html or the css files of the components.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you really want? I think you need one component to call component one and component two, maybe we can call the container component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fkg3uj?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Yes, because the second component changes with the button from the first component. Is creating a container component the only way to achieve this?

Comment: If the first and second positioning side by side,  you can use @Input on second component to make changes from first component into second component with passing value from first component to second component.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Will do this if I don't have any other option.

Comment: I'm sorry I was typo, I mean if the first and second component positioning ...

Answer (score 0):

From the above Question, what I understand is that you want one component beside another. What I suggest doing is to make use of the main component which will import both the first and second components. This will help you in data sharing also and placing the two components adjacent.
Here is a link for the repo where I have utilized the same technique.
[git repo link for example](https://github.com/Rohan-Ramesh-Jadhav/componet-routing)

To use the above example project,
step 1: clone the repo
step 2: execute 'npm install' to install node-modules
step 3: then 'ng serve' to see the results in the browser listens to localhost:4200.

If you want to call a component within the component and show it beside each other, then drop a message.

Comment: Thanks! But what I'm trying to achieve is to call a component within another component and display them beside each other.

Comment: @KleinThePenguin if that is the case then check this repo once. Here I have modified the code for the same you asked for. I am using bootstrap for alignment and design. Using bootstrap 5 I can create flex columns and rows easily. If you are using the same then well and good. Else either you must use some other framework or pure CSS for it. Link to Repo: https://github.com/Rohan-Ramesh-Jadhav/component-within-component

Comment: UPDATE: @KleinThePenguin you can check the code in this link directly. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xkduaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts